# robots.txt for a CodeIgniter based website?

Tags: robots.txt, googlebot, codeigniter

I am working on a php site that uses Code Igniter framework and has the following folder structure on the server.

> public_html
>
> - application
> - public
> - sql
> - style
> - system
> - design
> - images
> - js
> - plugin
>
> .htaccess
>
> robots.txt
>
> sitemap.xml
>
> index.php

The bulleted list of items are subfolders under public_html.

The **application** folder contains the code consisting of views and controllers.

My question is,

> should **googlebot** be able to crawl folders other than **application**?

OR

> should I **Disallow** all folders other than **application** so that no search engine bot gets to crawl other folders?

Comment: One thing I'm confused about this question is this questioner has put his robot.txt in root directory and I in public_html. What's the exact place??

Answer (score 2):

Your images folder might be useful if you want images to appear in google image search.

Everything else should probably be disallowed.

Answer (score 1):

No search engine spider would even know about the application folder and thus not be able to crawl it anyway. They would only see what URLs you provide from the home page.

Actually IIRC the `.htaccess` file CI supplies should only allow access to specific folders like `images` so the application folder should never be accessible. So you don't really need to block anything in robots.txt.